# Grails 2.5 - generate String based on id during insert

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a field `String generated` in the domain class, and I'd like to set `generated` based on the `id` when the value is inserted. For example, `generated` might get set to generated100 if the `id` is 100. I'd ideally like to do this behind the scenes, so calling `new DomainClass().save(flush: true)` would automatically process and save `generated` along with the rest of DomainClass. Is this possible to do without turning the `save()` line into two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you read the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) regarding `afterInsert`. There you can implement whatever logic you want and have it encapsulated in your domain class.